# Problem while sending JSON DATA

Tags: vb.net, json, json.net

I have to pass my Json data in a particular format. 
My app is coded in vb.

The following is my code :

```
 Dim jsonObject As New Json.JsonObject
    jsonObject.Item("count") = New Json.JsonNumber("0")
     jsonObject.Item("data") = New Json.JsonArray("")
    **jsonObject.Item("success") = New Json.JsonString("True")**

    The Problem lies in the line :
```

jsonObject.Item("success") = New Json.JsonString("True") .
        The error message being shown is " Type 'Jayrock.Json.JsonString' has no constructors."

Just to add i have imported the associated libraries .

What should I do to tackle this problem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simply like this:

```
Dim jsonObject As New Json.JsonObject  
jsonObject.Item("count") = 0  
jsonObject.Item("data") = New Json.JsonArray()  
jsonObject.Item("success") = "True"
```

In other words, you can use primitive types like string and integer as values.